# Quality of being unsafe to anyone who doesn't know what they are doing and rewarding to anyone who does

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word (an adjective) that describes something that is likely to cause bad consequences if gone after/considered/executed. Basically one is likely to regret if they mess with it. Or, another way to put it, one has to realize all ins-and-outs before committing/choosing to go this way, otherwise they are likely to regret it.

I tend to think that the meaning of 'risky' is close to what I am looking for, but I don't think it hits the spot 100% because taking a risk implies relying on luck: if one is lucky enough everything will be all right, if not then, well, bad luck. But what I am asking about doesn't have anything to do with being lucky, it's rather being smart and understanding what you are doing.

So the idea is to come up with a right word that clearly says to the random people to keep out, so they don't hurt themselves.

Comment: Risky sounds good, or simply dangerous.

Comment: I think hazardous is also good.

Comment: From a thesaurus: _dangerous, hazardous, perilous, high-risk, unsafe, precarious, treacherous_. Unfortunately, you've made your question so generic that I can't recommend any one of these in particular. You aim to describe something "likely to cause bad consequences if being gone after/considered/executed," where one must consider "all ins-and-outs before committing/choosing to go this way." That could describe starting an affair, taking illegal drugs, running with scissors, or a host of other things. All of those thesaurus entries are good, but which one is best depends on the circumstances.

Comment: *I tend to think that meaning of 'risky' is close to what I am looking for, but I don't think it hits the spot 100%.* Explain why you don't think risky fits and people might be able to help you find a better word.

Comment: @starsplusplus, because taking a risk implies relying on luck, if one is lucky enough everything will be all right, if not then, well, bad luck. Now, what I am asking about doesn't have anything to do with being lucky, it's rather being smart and understand what you are doing.

Comment: [“Tricky”](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+tricky)? [“Delicate” (3)](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+tricky)? [“Dicey”](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+dicey)?

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the idea that taking a risk necessarily implies a component of luck. Some situations may involve a risk that is driven by luck, while another may be a risk driven by, say, the prospective skill of the operator of a machine that could cause harm. You could easily have situations in which a "calculated risk" did not involve random chance at all.

Comment: More context, please!

Comment: Yes, I agree with David about calculated risks. (Depends a little on your definition of "luck" too. OP seems to be using it to mean "a particular type of random chance than cannot be anticipated or calculated in advance".)

Comment: @starsplusplus, taking risk always assumes taking chances, the difference between the calculated risk and reckless risk is that in the former case either outcome is assessed as acceptable, in later case only the positive outcome is thought to be acceptable, however randomness (or luck) doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, you are at the split of 2 roads the first one is long but smooth and safe, the other one is over the mountain and assumes you know and good at mount climbing. Obviously if you are not stupid and you can't do mountain climbing you choose the safer one, if you are a professional climber you go the second one, because it's not a problem for you and you can save some time. Now the question is about a quality of being unsafe if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @468 Yes, I know. That's why I clarified on the "luck" thing. My reading of your question and comments was that you wanted a word that allowed for calculated risk but not blind luck.

Comment: @468 In that case, I would probably go with [“demanding”](https://www.google.com/search?oq=define+demanding) and reinforce the potential for reward with other words. [“Advanced”](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/advanced) might split the difference, and you might also look at [“challenging”](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/challenging).

Answer (score 3):

I am going to be bold enough to suggest the best word is *perilous.* The words suggested in some of the comments all have a degree of validity to them, but the tone of your question to me suggests a notion that is somehow better conveyed by perilous.

I realize that, at a most basic level, perilous and hazardous are generally equivalent. I do offer, however, that perilous tends to convey the consideration of an action that carries with it a risk - which is what you specifically requested. A person walking down the street may encounter *hazards*, such as broken sidewalks, but *peril* (and, hence, *perilous*) conveys something more immediate and threatening.

Respectfully submitted for your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like "life-altering" is a good way to express this. It sounds like you're describing something that isn't inherently good or bad, but it's associated with a significant number of consequences that one must consider carefully before willingly engaging in it. It has the potential to seriously impact or alter someone's way of life.